# PostgreSQL (Django - Production ) - Function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I just hosted my Django website on pythonanywhere with paid account. I am using Postgresql database, Everything is working fine but TrigramSimilarity is not working. In local host everything is working fine but in production it gives error. kindly help me , i have been searching but haven't found anything. Thanks in advance.

Error:
Exception Value:
function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Comment: Did you create the pg_trgm extension?

Comment: I already created via postgresql terminal. But it's not working, however if i create via bash terminal, it gives this error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create extension "pg_trgm"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.

Comment: Had you connected to the specific database that you are using when you created it from a postgres terminal?  I think you need to create it specifically in each DB.

Comment: Connect to the database you are working on with superuser. In some cases, the superuser is `postgres`. Then run the command `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`